# Adding an URL prefix to Jenkins server configuration

Tags: apache, jenkins

I am running Jenkins on my own web-server (Ubuntu with Apache2) that is accessible via dyndns. My goal is to reach Jenkins by using the following URL:

```
https://myPrivateURL.dyndns-office.com:444/jenkins/
```

So I configured my Apache like this:

[image]

This makes Jenkins accessible if I enter https://myPrivateURL.dyndns-office.com:444/jenkins/ within my browser. However, not all links within the Jenkins-pages are correct. E.g. consider the menu entries to the left including “New Job”, “Manage Jenkins” etc:

[image]

When clicking on “Manage Jenkins” the server tries to find the following URL:

```
 https://myPrivateURL.dyndns-office.com:444/manage
```

However, the URL should include “jenkins” within the path. The following URL would be the right one (and works if manually entered)

```
 https://myPrivateURL.dyndns-office.com:444/jenkins/manage
```

**So here comes the question:**

How do I configure Jenkins so that a prefix is used to build the Jenkins-URLs? Here is what I tried:

I opened /etc/default/jenkins and appended  “--prefix=/jenkins/” to JENKINS_ARGS

[image]

However, if I try to open https://myPrivateURL.dyndns-office.com:444/jenkins/ after restarting Jenkins I always get the same error message:

[image]

It does not matter what I enter as a prefix. Even if I use “abcdefg” as the prefix the error message remains the same. /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log simply says

> [Winstone 2014/01/02 XX:XX:XX] - Request URL / not found - doesn't
>   match any webapp prefix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was close:

```
ProxyPass /jenkins/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins/ http://localhost:8080/
```

has to be

```
ProxyPass /jenkins/ http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins/ http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
```

Comment: Yup. More info can be found here : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache